# On the set of non-zero elements in an integral domain whose generating principal ideal is of a special kind

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $R$ be an integral domain. Consider the set $$S := \big\{a \in R\smallsetminus \{0\} 
 : Ra+Rx \text{ is a principal ideal } \forall x \in R \big \}.$$ Is $S$ a saturated multiplicative closed subset of $R$? If in general $S$ is not saturated or multiplicative closed, what if we assume $R$ is a GCD domain? Is the claim true then ?

If we assume $R$ is local , let $x \in R$ , then $a \in S \implies   \exists d \in R $ such that $Ra+Rx=Rd$ , where $d | a , d|x$ , then let $a'=a/d , x '=x/d$ , then $Ra'+Rx '=R$ , but $R$ is a local ring , hence one of $a' $ and $x'$ must be a unit i.e. either $a|x$ or $x|a$ . Thus in a local ring $R$ ,

$\big\{a \in R\smallsetminus \{0\} 
 : Ra+Rx \text{ is a principal ideal } \forall x \in R \big \} $

$=\{a \in R \smallsetminus \{0\} : $ for every $x \in R$ , either $x|a$ or $a|x\}$ ; and I can show that in any integral

domain , $\{a \in R \smallsetminus \{0\} : $ for every $x \in R$ , either $x|a$ or $a|x\}$ is a saturated multiplicative closed set .

I have no idea what happens if the ring is not local .

Comment: don't use spacing before punctuation. Fixed now

Comment: @users I would be glad to know the context of your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is **yes** if $R$ is any [atomic domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_domain), e.g., $R$ is a Noetherian domain.

> > **Claim 1.** Let $R$ be any integral domain. The set $S = S_R$ is saturated in the sense that if $ab \in S_R$ for some $a,b \in R$, then $a \in S_R$.
> >
> > *Proof.* Let $x \in R$ and let $I = Ra + Rx$. As $Ib$ is principal, so is $I$.
> >
> > **Lemma.** Let $R$ be any integral domain. If $p \in S_R$ is irreducible, then $Rp$ is maximal. In particular, $p$ is prime.
> >
> > *Proof.* Let $p$ be an irreducible element in $S_R$. Given $x \in R \setminus Rp$, there is $d \in R$ such that $Rp + Rx = Rd$. As $d$ divides both $p$ and $x$ and $p$ doesn't divide $x$, the element $d$ is a unit. Therefore $Rp + Rx = R$.
> >
> > **Claim 2.** If $R$ is an atomic domain, then $S_R$ is multiplicatively closed.
> >
> > *Proof.* Since $S_R$ is saturated and $R$ is atomic, it suffices to show that $pa \in S_R$ for every irreducible element $p \in S_R$ and every $a \in S_R$.
> >     To do so, consider $x \in R$. If $x \in Rp$, write $x = px'$. As $a \in S_R$, there is $d \in R$ such that $Ra + Rx' = Rd$. Hence $Rpa + Rx = Rpd$. If $x \notin Rp$, then $Rp + Rx = R$ by the above lemma. As $a \in S_R$, we can find $d \in R$ such that $Ra + Rx = Rd$. Writing $1$ (resp. $d$) as a linear combination of $p$ and $x$ (resp. of $a$ and $x$), we observe that $d = 1 \cdot d \in Rpa + Rx$. Therefore $Rpa + Rx = Rd$, which completes the proof.

Let us denote by $R^{\times}$ the unit group of $R$.
The obvious examples of sets $S_R$ are $R \setminus \{0\}$ (obtained, e.g., when $R$ is a [Bézout domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout_domain)) and $R^{\times}$ (obtained, e.g., for $R = \mathbb{Z}[X]$, a non-Bézout [unique factorization domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain)).

If $R$ is atomic, the above proof shows that $S_R$ is the multiplicative sub[monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) of $R \setminus \{0\}$ generated the units of $R$ and the prime elements $p$ of $R$ such that $Rp$ is a maximal ideal of $R$. Hence it is not too difficult to find rings $R$  such that $R^{\times} \subsetneq S_R \subsetneq R \setminus \{0\}$. Indeed, we have

> > **Corollary.** Let $R$ be a [Dedekind domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_domain) which is not a PID, e.g., $R$ is the ring of integers of a number field with class number $> 1$. Then $S_R \subsetneq R \setminus \{0\}$.
> >
> > *Proof.* By assumption, we can find a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ which is not principal. Let $a \in \mathfrak{m} \setminus \{0\}$. The element $a$ cannot be a product of prime elements since otherwise $\mathfrak{m}$ would be principal ideal generated by one of them. As a result, $a \notin S_R$.

In the case $R = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$, we have $S_R = R \setminus \mathfrak{m}$ where $\mathfrak{m} = R \cdot 2 + R \cdot (1 + \sqrt{-5})$. More generally, if $R$ is the ring of integers of some number field, then $S_R$ is the complement of the union of finitely many non-principal maximal ideals.

Claim 1 can be used to inspect the state of affairs regarding polynomial rings $R[X]$ with $R$ an integral domain. For those rings $R$, the set $S = S_{R[X]}$ is one of the two trivial sets on many instances.
We call $f \in R[X]$ a *$u$-polynomial* if $f(r)$ is a unit of $R$ for every $r \in R$.

> > **Claim 3.** Let $R$ be an integral domain which is not a field. Assume moreover that $R$ is a unique factorization domain (UFD) with infinitely many primes or that there is no non-constant $u$-polynomial over $R$. 
> >     Then $S_{R[X]} = (R[X])^{\times} \simeq R^{\times}$.
> >
> > *Proof.* We begin with an observation. Let $a, b \in R$. As the ideal generated by $a$ and $X - b$ is principal if and only if $a \in R^{\times}$, we deduce that $a \notin S_{R[X]}$ and $X - b \notin S_{R[X]}$ for every $a \in R \setminus R^{\times}$ and every $b \in R$. Now let $f \in S_{R[X]}$ and let $a \in R \setminus \{0\}$. The ideal generated by $f$ and $a$ is a principal ideal generated by some $g \in R[X]$. Since $g$ divides $a$ and $f$, it is a constant polynomial which lies in $S_{R[X]}$ by Claim 1. Hence $g$ is unit of $R$ by the above remark. As result, the reduction of $f$ modulo $Ra$ is a unit of $(R/aR)[X]$ for every non-zero element $a$ of $R$. If $R$ is a UFD with infinitely many primes, then $f$ must be a constant polynomial, hence a unit. 
> >     Otherwise, let us consider the ideal generated by $f$ and $X - b$ for some $b \in R$. It is a principal ideal generated by some $h \in R[X]$ which divides both $f$ and $X - b$. As it cannot be $X - b$ multiplied by a unit of $R$ by our first remark, it is a unit of $R$. Therefore $f(b)$ is a unit of $R$ too. Since this holds for every $b \in R$, $f$ is $u$-polynomial.

Note that non-constant $u$-polynomials over UFDs which aren't fields **do exist**, see e.g., [1, Example 3.b]. Indeed, take $\mathcal{P} =\{p \text{ prime } \vert\, p \equiv 3 \text{ mod } 4 \} \subset \mathbb{Z}$ and set $$\mathbb{Z}_{\mathcal{P}} = \{ \text{ rational numbers } \frac{m}{n} \text{ with no prime factor of } n \text{ in } \mathcal{P}\}.$$ Then $x^2 + 1$ is $u$-polynomial over the UFD $\mathbb{Z}_{\mathcal{P}}$.

In the course of Claim 3's proof, we showed

> > **Claim 4.** Let $R$ be an integral domain which is not a field. Then 
> >     every element of $S_{R[X]}$ is a $u$-polynomial over $R$.

This easily yields

> > **Claim 5.** Let $R$ be any integral domain. Then 
> >     $S_{R[X, Y]} = (R[X, Y])^{\times} \simeq R^{\times}$.
> >
> > *Proof.* Cleary, $R[X]$ is not a field. Let $f(X, Y) \in (R[X])[Y]$ be a non-constant polynomial with coefficients in $R[X]$. Then $f(X, X^n)$ is a non-constant polynomial with coefficients in $R$ for all $n$ large enough. Therefore $f(X, Y)$ isn't a $u$-polynomial over $R[X]$. Consequently, $u$-polynomials over $R[X]$ are constant polynomials and the result follows from Claim 4.

The OP defines a seemingly narrower set $$N_R = \{ a \in R \setminus \{0\} : a \vert x \text{ or } x \vert a \text{ for every } x \in R\}$$ which satisfies $$R^{\times} \subset N_R \subset S_R \subset R \setminus \{0\}.$$

> > **OP's first claim**. If $R$ is a local domain, then $S_R = N_R$.
> >
> > **OP's second claim**. If $R$ is any integral domain, then $N_R$ is multiplicatively closed and saturated.

From this, we infer

> > **Corollary 1.** If $R$ is an atomic domain with at least two non-associated irreducible elements, then $N_R = R^{\times}.$
> >
> > *Proof.* As $R$ has at least two non-associated irreducible elements, $N_R$ cannot contain any irreducible element. Since $N_R$ is saturated and $R$ is atomic,  $N_R$  cannot contain any non-unit element.

In particular, we have $S_R = R^{\times}$ for any regular local domain $R$ which is not a principal ideal domain. We also obtain

> > **Remark.** If $R$ is a principal ideal domain with more than one prime, then $R^{\times} = N_R \subsetneq S_R = R \setminus \{ 0 \}$.

We obtain an alternative for Noetherian local domains $R$ with Krull dimension $1$: either $R$ is a principal ideal domain and obviously $S_R = R \setminus \{ 0 \}$, or $R$ isn't and $S_R = R^{\times}$. This follows from

> > **Corollary 2.** Assume that $R$ is an atomic domain such that $S_R = N_R$, e.g, $R$ is a Noetherian local domain. Then either $R$ is a [discrete valuation ring (DVR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_valuation_ring) and $S_R = R \setminus \{0\}$ or $S_R = R^{\times}$.
> >
> > *Proof.* Assume that $S_R$ contains a non-unit element. As $R$ is atomic and $S_R$ is saturated, the set $S_R$ contains an irreducible element $p$. Since $p \in N_R$, the element $p$ divides any non-unit of $R$. Therefore $Rp$ is the unique maximal ideal of $R$. Since an irreducible element of $R$ lies necessarily in $Rp$, $p$ is the unique irreducible element of $R$, up to multiplication by a unit. Since $R$ is atomic $R$, we deduce that $R$ is a DVR.

---

[1] S. H. Weintraub, "Values of polynomials over integral domains", 2014.

Comment: I also don't know of any examples ... but that shouldn't stop us from trying to prove or disprove the claim ... your proof of saturated ness is nice and simple , though I know this trick , I totally missed it here ..

Comment: Here is the proof that the set you mention (call it $S$ say) is saturated : Let $ab \in S$ and let $t\in R$ ; then either $ab | tb $ or $tb | ab$ ; now , since $b \neq 0$ , so if $ab | tb$ then $a|t$ and if $tb |ab$ then $t|a$ ; so either $a|t$ or $t|a$ and $t \in R$ was arbitrary , so $a  \in S$

Comment: Suppose for an integral domain $R$ , the set in the question say $S_R$ is multiplicatively closed ; then is $S_{R[X]}$ also multiplicatively closed  in $R[X]$ ? (We already know it is saturated ... )

Comment: @users I just modified my answer to settle the case of atomic domains. It answers your new question for domains which satisfy the ascending condition on principal ideals.

Comment: @users I just added Claim 5 which also relates to your new question.

Comment: @users I corrected and simplified the proof of Claim 2.

Comment: Your proof of claim 2 still contains a typo .. $1$ can be written as a linear combination of $p$ and $x$ , not $a$ and $x$ ... as far the motivation of the question regrads , I was just tryinv to see various properties related to domains having some good factorial or arithmetical prooerties and then trying to isolate the elements with special properties ... I am thinking about vatious othet related properties , I will post about it here if I need help seeing as good a response as yours ...

Comment: @users The typo is now corrected, thanks. I expanded my answer by giving an example of ring $R$ such that $R^{\times} \subsetneq S_R \subsetneq R \setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: Assuming $R$ is a GCD domain i.e. $Ra \cap Rb$ is a principal ideal for every $a,b \in R$ , (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GCD_domain) , can you show that $S_R$ is multiplicatively closed ? Assuming $R$ is a Prufer domain , (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_domain) , can you show that $S_R$ is multiplicatively closed ?

Comment: @users I am unable to show anything assuming $R$ is a GCD. If I had time, I would try to generalize the claim about multiplicative closedness to some generalizations of atomic rings ("Non-Noetherian commutative ring theory" by S.T. Chapman and S. Glaz looks like a good place to start from) and strive for the search of a non-atomic counter-examples.

Comment: Okay ... what about Prufer domains ?

Comment: @users It is quite the same to me. My 2 cents: relax the atomic assumption until it breaks mulitplicative closedness. You may find then (counter)examples which are GCD or Prüfer.

Comment: I had some difficulty understanding your corollary about ideal class groups. How do you get that there is a maximal ideal whose ideal class is non-trivial and has finite order ? I can see that from $\mathcal m^n=Ra$ , and $\mathcal m$ not principal, we can conclude that $a$ is not a product of primes, but how does that imply that $a \notin S_R$ ?

Comment: @users I simplified the proof of the corollary. Since a Dedekind domain $R$ is atomic, $S_R$ is generated by the units of $R$ and the prime elements $p$ such that $Rp$ is a maximal ideal.

Comment: Is every maximal ideal class an element of finite order in the ideal class group of a Dedekind domain ? (you seem to be using so in your corollary about ideal class groups)

Comment: Every Abelian group is isomorphic to the ideal class group of some Dedekind domain, so the answer is no in general, although it holds for rings of integers. The only hypothesis is that $R$ is not a PID, so it has a non-principal maximal (= non-zero prime) ideal.

Comment: what is your $a$ in the argument ?

Comment: Oops, this is a non-zero element of $\mathfrak{m}$, just corrected.

Comment: If $a$ is a product of prime elements then why would $\mathfrak m$ be a principal ideal generated by one of them ? I can only see that $\mathfrak m$ contains a principal ideal generated by one of them ...

Comment: This is just enough as  such prime is maximal.

Comment: We know that $S_R$ is always saturated. Let $\hat S_R$ be the multiplicative submonoid generated by $S_R$ and the unit of $R$; is $\hat S_R$ still saturated ?

Comment: @users  Yes if $R$ is a UFD, but I have no idea in general. Considering examples may help.

Comment: In your claim 5, is $R$ really any non-field integral domain (no UFD or extra assumption?) ? I don't see how does it follow ...

Comment: @users I have now added a proof of Claim 5.